# How to make checkbox checked based on the data from database in mvc 4 entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am strong checkbox checked data in db. If the checkbox was checked i want to display it as checked in view. Is it possible to achieve this?
Here is my supporting code.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
           var groups = db.tm_grp_group.Where(a=>a.grp_isactive==true);
           var permissions = db.tm_perm_level;
            GroupPermissionVM model = new GroupPermissionVM
             {
              GroupList = new SelectList(groups, "grp_id", "grp_name"),
              Permissions = permissions.Select(p => new PermissionVM
               {
                  perm_id = p.perm_id,
                  perm_levelname = p.perm_levelname

               })
             };
          return View(model);
        }
```

This is index.cshtml

```
@model Permission.Models.GroupPermissionVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
      @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.GroupID)

               @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GroupID, Model.GroupList, "Please select", new { id = "ddlgrp" })
          @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Permissions)

        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    }
```

Inside Home/Editortemplate/PermissionVM.cshtml

```
@model Permission.Models.PermissionVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PermissionVM";
}
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.perm_id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.perm_description)
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.perm_status)
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.perm_status,Model.perm_levelname)
</div>
```

I have table structure like this

```
   grp_id  perm_id
1   1      1
2   2      2
     permlevel_name    perm_status
1   Screen Level       True
2   custom Level       True
```

Grp_id is dropdownlistbox in this context. So if i select 1 corresponding permlevel_name is screen level and it is checked. So when i make selection as 1 below screenlevel checkbox should be cheked. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: It not clear what you table structure is. Which table are you referring to and for what model. And have you shown the fields for one table or 2 tables (each with 2 fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code where you call PermissionVM.cshtml File.

Comment: My db got changed,requirement changed. Thanks for all whoever tried me to answer